# React - passing props up components tree through functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to pass a simple string, number or boolean up more than one level in my component tree. From what I read I need to do this with callback functions but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Here is a sample of where I pass a prop down from Parent App to grandchild Breadcrumb. I would like this prop to actually come from the last child in the tree, the "ResultsPage" component.

I realise there are better ways of doing sth like this (redux, context, different structure, etc), the point here for me is learning and to understand how to use callback functions and how to pass a prop up several more than 1 level.

Newbie friendly please - thanks for any input :)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Top level app</h1>

        {/* I import the header and pass down prop */}
        <Header currentLocation="Results Page" />

        {/* I import the main app content */}
        <ResultsPage />
      </>
    );
  }
}

function Header(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>
        This is the header element. It will have some nav items and the
        breadcrumb I import
      </h2>

      {/* I import the breadcrumb accept the props from parent and pass the props down to child */}
      <Crumbs currentLocation={props.currentLocation} />
    </>
  );
}

function Crumbs(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* I display the props I passed down through the tree */}
      <h3>
        <small>This is the breadcrumb, you are on</small>{" "}
        {props.currentLocation}
      </h3>
    </>
  );
}

function ResultsPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
        This is the actual results content. I would like this component to tell
        the header component that I have loaded so it can update the breadcrumb
        to let it know which page is currently loaded in the app.
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

To complete this issue I lewave the following solutions:

[Codesandbox: Solution to the initial question](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pass-state-up-and-props-down-wb03r?file=/src/App.js)

[Codesandbox: Additional solution for the same problem using only functional components](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pass-state-up-and-props-down-with-functional-components-s1v67?file=/src/App.js)

Hope it helps the next guy :)

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have spent literally 2 full days reading tutorials and documentation. My problem is that they are always very complex, or they use class components and I have trouble translating that to function components, or they use state when I really just want to send a prop and so on. It was the same when I tried to understand what I have above: how to pass a prop down several layers. I could not find any simnple examples. So it took me literally days to weed through tutorials and documentation until I was able to build this very simple component tree you see above. The above has helped me understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a local state variable to store the location, and pass a callback function through the props to set it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentLocation : "InitialLocation"
    }
  }

  changeCurrentLocation = (newLocation) => {
    this.setState({currentLocation : newLocation})
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <ResultsPage callback={this.changeCurrentLocation}/>
  }
}
```

The changeCurrentLocation function takes the new location as argument and modifies the state. Everytime the state changes, the render function is called again. This would refresh the view with updated state information, in your case - currentLocation.

```
function ResultsPage({ callback }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    callback('My Results');
  }, [callback])

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Edison, I tried this but it throws up errors:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-props-up-wb03r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: There were a few gotcha's with the initial answer here, which I have ammended to fix: changeCurrentLocation must use an arrow function inorder to keep the correct `this` in scope, and callback should not be called in the render function as that will cause an infinte loop (on render, callback is called which sets state, which triggers another render which causes callback to be called again, etc)

https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-props-up-o6scl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Many thanks Josh! This works and I actually managed to figure out how to consume the new state, too :)

I have updated the Sandbox and I will comment all the lines for my own understanding until I figure out exactly what you did there.

Comment: Thankyou @Josh , I am newbie to Answering questions in StackOverflow too. Chris, Please accept the answer if it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Edison and Josh, thanks for your time. I accepted the answer but @edison, you should really update your version with Josh's update so the next person to read this can have a working sample.

I commented the various elements and cleaned up a little, fully working answer can be seen here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-state-up-and-props-down-wb03r?file=/src/App.js:0-1934

Answer (score -2):

Best way is to do this as I think keep the state inside a redux store. You can create a listener using `subscribe()` method in the redux to listen any dispatches from the child components from the parent component.

Also there is some easy method, You can use localstorage.  You can store value from the child component and listen it by the parent component using `window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  }` callback method. I hope you can understand what I tried to say.

Comment: This problem is easily solved in React with callback props, rather than bringing in an entirely new library. 

Additionally, using localStorage to propagate changes is not recommended as it can be difficult to understand where these values are kept, and disrupts the unidirectional flow of data.

Comment: Thank you Sandun. I have started reading Redux docs but I think it's a little out of my league for now :)